# Ensuring unique values in dplyr::summarise() in most efficient way

Tags: r, dplyr, unique, paste

I usually have a tibble with lots of columns of type `character` (between 20 and 30) and only 3-4 columns of type `numeric`.

Grouping and summarizing the numeric columns is super fast, but my approach to summarizing the character columns while ensuring unique values per grouping var value is pretty slow in total.

Just wondering if there is some faster way out there than using `paste()` for this.

```
library(magrittr)

make_unique <- function(x, sep = "-") {
  ifelse(length(x_unique <- unique(x)) == 1, x_unique,
    paste(sort(x_unique), collapse = sep))
}

make_unique_2 <- function(x, sep = "-") {
  paste(sort(x), collapse = sep)
}

df <- tibble::tribble(
  ~id, ~country, ~value,
  "a",   "A",   10,
  "a",   "B",   20,
  "b",   "A",   5,
  "c",   "A",   100,
  "c",   "B",   1,
  "c",   "C",   25
)

df %>%
  dplyr::group_by(id) %>%
  dplyr::summarise_if(is.character, make_unique) %>%
  dplyr::ungroup()
#> # A tibble: 3 x 2
#>   id    country
#>   <chr> <chr>  
#> 1 a     A-B    
#> 2 b     A      
#> 3 c     A-B-C

microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
  "numeric" = df %>%
    dplyr::group_by(id) %>%
    dplyr::summarise_if(is.numeric, sum) %>%
    dplyr::ungroup(),
  "character_1" = df %>%
    dplyr::group_by(id) %>%
    dplyr::summarise_if(is.character, make_unique) %>%
    dplyr::ungroup(),
  "character_2" = df %>%
    dplyr::group_by(id) %>%
    dplyr::summarise_if(is.character, make_unique_2) %>%
    dplyr::ungroup()
)
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>         expr    min      lq     mean  median      uq    max neval
#>      numeric 1.0554 1.24160 1.918480 1.43135 1.90180 8.7733   100
#>  character_1 1.1907 1.37530 2.093501 1.60895 2.04235 7.7648   100
#>  character_2 1.2255 1.44185 2.474062 1.69260 2.38540 9.4851   100
```

Created on 2019-04-05 by the reprex package (v0.2.1)

Comment: Looks almost similar in benchmarks

Comment: Also, in the `make_unique`, it may be better to have `if/else` loop instead of `ifelse`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On a bigger dataset,  we will see some changes in benchmarks with respect to `make_unique_2`

-new function

```
make_unique_3 <- function(x, sep="-") {
  x_unique <- unique(x)
  if(length(x_unique) == 1) x_unique else paste(sort(x_unique), collapse= sep)
   }

make_unique_4 <- function(x, sep="-") {
   x_unique <- unique(x)
   if(n_distinct(x_unique) == 1) x_unique else str_c(sort(x_unique), collapse=sep)

 }
```

-data

```
 df <- df[rep(1:nrow(df), 1e5), ]
```

-benchmark

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
   "numeric" = df %>%
     dplyr::group_by(id) %>%
     dplyr::summarise_if(is.numeric, sum) %>%
     dplyr::ungroup(),
   "character_1" = df %>%
     dplyr::group_by(id) %>%
     dplyr::summarise_if(is.character, make_unique) %>%
     dplyr::ungroup(),
   "character_2" = df %>%
     dplyr::group_by(id) %>%
     dplyr::summarise_if(is.character, make_unique_2) %>%
     dplyr::ungroup(),
     "character_3" = df %>%
       dplyr::group_by(id) %>%
       dplyr::summarise_if(is.character, make_unique_3) %>%
       dplyr::ungroup(),
       "character_4" = df %>%
         dplyr::group_by(id) %>%
         dplyr::summarise_if(is.character, make_unique_4) %>%
         dplyr::ungroup(),   
       unit = "relative", times = 10L
 )
```

-output

```
#Unit: relative
#        expr      min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
#     numeric 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000 1.000000    10  a 
# character_1 1.681810 1.614818 1.625383 1.636651 1.616881 1.489384    10  a 
# character_2 7.668509 7.207077 7.117084 6.992513 6.102214 9.102668    10   b
# character_3 1.671742 1.618976 1.632336 1.710828 1.587933 1.501431    10  a 
# character_4 1.444589 1.435881 1.504313 1.562996 1.515468 1.479626    10  a
```

-comments

changing to `str_c` from `paste` increased the efficiency from 1.68 to 1.44 (`make_unique` vs `make_unique_4`)